# Add data to Angular form in controller

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular and am trying to get it to create a new Droplet from a form using my API. I can get it to submit my form data correctly but I need to add a hidden field for a user ID. I assume the best way is to add this in the controller before sending it to my factory to be sent as POST request. My controller looks like this:

```
$scope.createNewDroplet = function () {
  drop.create($scope.drop).success(function(droplet) {
    $scope.createdDroplet = droplet;
  });
};
```

And the factory looks like this:

```
app.factory('drop', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    create: function (drop) {
      return $http.post('/droplets/', drop)
    }
  }
}]);
```

I have access to the user id through $scope.user.id. How would I go about adding "user_id: $scope.user.id" to the request?

Comment: Why do you need a hidden field? If it is to post the data back to the server simply create a new object to be posted in the angular function.

Comment: Yes but how do I do that? That's the problem. I'm new to angular and I'm not sure how to add the user_id (or any other extra info) to the data from the form to send to the server.

Comment: I guess angular way won't be creating a hidden field for it, that might be helpful in frameworks like rails and django which picks the hidden field values as params while requesting.

Comment: ashish, I'm not creating a hidden field. I'm trying to do the same thing which is pass additional data along with the form in the request to the server.

Comment: Oh, then you can just add it to javascript object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
$http.post('/droplets/', {drop: drop, userId: $scope.user.id})
```

Edit

In answer to your comment about not being able to access scope in the factory...

Change the data in your controller before calling your factory code.

```
$scope.createNewDroplet = function () {
  $scope.drop.user_id = $scope.user.id;
  drop.create($scope.drop).success(function(droplet) {
    $scope.createdDroplet = droplet;
  });
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't access $scope inside the factory. What I need to do is add the user_id: $scope.user.id to the form data in the controller. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Finnjon - edited answer to add userid to json in controller before calling the factory.

Comment: I got it working now. The code you used was in the right place but it was easiest to just add the user_id to the existing drop that has a few fields already from the form. 

$scope.drop.user_id = $scope.user.id

Comment: Good, glad to hear it:) - please can you mark it as an the answer if you think it is?